# Java Spring ajax loader gif freezes after two loops

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jquery-ui

Below is the js and jsp file of my ajax loader that the gif freezes after two cycles. Infinite loop does not work in JAVA, anyone have any suggestions for stopping my gif from freezing.

#### dashboardnew.js

```
var DASHBOARDNEW = {

        showBusy: function() {
            // console.log('showBusy ajax_load_busy');
            $("#ajax_load_busy").modal('show');
        },
        
        hideBusy: function() {
            // console.log('hideBusy ajax_load_busy');
            $("#ajax_load_busy").modal('hide');
            
        }
        
};
```

dashboardnew.jsp

```
<div id="ajax_load_busy" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="ajax_load_busy" id="load_busy">
                <img
                    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean Java**Script**? Java is a completely different language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?